# Tag-revision edits welcome?

Tags: discussion

I just added 'entomology' tag to a few species ID posts about insects before I noticed that edits are supposed to be 'substantial'. Is tidying up tags discouraged? (If so, apologising in advance...)

edit: I should have said, I did search for 'tag' in the help area but couldn't find anything clarifying this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as you're not retagging a large amount of questions at once, that is perfectly fine. If the question has other issues aside from the tag, you should fix them at the same time, but if it doesn't, just editing the tags is okay.

Retagging too many questions at once fills up the frontpage with those questions, to avoid that you should not edit that many questions at once, but in batches and wait a while before retagging the next batch.